# How can i split string with the operators?

Tags: java, regex

I am new to regex,and i want to ask some help how can i split my string with multiple delimeters. so that i can get 4 5 30

String mystring = "4*5-30";

```
String [] str = mystring.split("'*','-','/','+'");
```

Comment: It's just a regex, so...

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Comment: Hi @OliCharlesworth,why you give me down votes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a [Character Class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) with the delimiters you want to split on.

```
String s = "4*5-30";
String[] parts = s.split("[*+/-]");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts)); //=> [4, 5, 30]
```

Comment: Hi,thank you for the reply..can you tell me why we should put inside those operators in [ ] ?

Comment: @hwnd The '*' character should be escaped?

Comment: @user3740532 It is nicely explained in linked article.

Comment: @PrahaladDeshpande Doesn't need escaped while inside a character class.

Comment: @user3740532 In the regular expression syntax ,the '[]' is used to specify an allowed range or choice of valid characters

Comment: @user3740532 by using a character class, you tell the regex engine to match only one out of several characters. A much easier way to combine the delimiters you want to match instead of trying to match them individually.